# program-o for android chat bot application

Tags: java, php, android, android-webservice

I am developing android chatbot application using [program-o](https://program-o.com/). I have program-o running on my localhost. I went through program-o documentation but still, I'm not able to understand what changes I need make to enable the communication between my Android app and program-o server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a php code to use program-o api.

Take the chat input from GET/POST parameters.

Use that input to get the output from program-o.

Parse that into json or any other format you like and print it.

Host that php file on a web server.

Now make an HTTP connection from android app. Give the input as parameters and parse the output received.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a LAMP server and run an instance of Program o
Json / xml rest api will interface will android app

You must use async task runner,httpresponse , and all.